# How to execute command and get output in both console and log file in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I would like to run an external windows command line executable within a Fortran application, get outputs in the console and in a text log file.

I am currently using Intel Fortran RUNQQ function that redirects the flow to the console but redirection to log file doesn't work.

`runqq(Exectable, Arguments // '> output.log')`

I also tried SYSTEM, SYSTEMQQ and EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE that enable to redirect the output to log file but not to the console.

`system('"' // Executable // '" ' // Arguments // '> output.log')
systemqq('"' // Executable // '" ' // Arguments // '> output.log')
call execute_command_line('"' // Executable // '" ' // Arguments // '> output.log')`

Is there any oter way to get output flow in both console and log file ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a .bat file contatining the commands that you intend to run (including the writing to .log file) and run this bat file in fortran instead?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I will try

Comment: I created a batch file containing my command line (including the flow redirection to log file) and run int using `RUNQQ('myfile.bat')`. It runs but the outputs don't appear in the main console view, should I launch the batch file by a different way to print the output flow in console ?

Comment: I think you have to choose either the console window or the log file. You cannot have both with simple output redirection. You have to create something that prints to both locations yourself, the simple redirection is not enough.

Comment: Well, at least on Unix platforms, you could use the "tee" utility to write both to the console and a log file. E.g. instead of "foo > output.log" you could do "foo | tee output.log". Maybe there exists something similar on Windows?